# Select container when selecting child radio buttons except for link inside div when unselected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be able to select a parent div and have it select its respective child radio button.

Inside this parent div there is a show/hide link that shows some info in a div that's also inside this container.

Problem is when I click the show/hide link of a parent div that isn't clicked, I want it to show/hide that hidden div without selecting that div's radio button/parent div.

Looking for a clean vanilla javascript solution.

In my code so far, it's not properly selecting the parent div of radio button, and then I want to make sure the show/hide link doesn't select the div if it wasn't already selected.

HTML

```
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 1</h3>
  <input id="radio1" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
  <div class="hiddenstuff">
    You see me now
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this)">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
<br />
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 2</h3>
  <input id="radio2" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
  <div class="hiddenstuff">
    You see me now
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this)">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checked {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.hiddenstuff {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```js
function check(box) {
  var radioId = this.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').value;
    document.getElementById(radioId).click();
  document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(function (item) {
    item.classList.remove("checked");
  });
  if ((input[0].checked = true)) {
    box.classList.add("checked");
  }
  return false;
}

function showhide(elem) {
  var cont = elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
  if (cont.style.display != "block") {
    cont.style.display = "block";
    elem.innerHTML = "hide";
  } else {
    cont.style.display = "none";
    elem.innerHTML = "show";
  }
  return false;
  elem.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checked {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.hiddenstuff {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 1</h3>
  <input id="radio1" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
  <div class="hiddenstuff">
    You see me now
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this)">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
<br />
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 2</h3>
  <input id="radio2" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
  <div class="hiddenstuff">
    You see me now
  </div>
  <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this)">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have to say I don't understand your "Problem.." part, wonted behavior.

Comment: When I click "show" link, I want it to show/hide the hiddenstuff div, but not click on the parent div/radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

If so, add `event.stopPropagation()`; at start of your clicking link function.

Also i believe your id fetching was wrong so i changed it:

`querySelectorAll` returns nod list, not element. Then you need to loop in it and fetch `.id` not `.value` to get the id.

```
var el = box.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
      var radioId = "";
      el.forEach(element => {
        radioId = element.id
      });
```

Use `box`, not `this`. Also `input[0]` was undefined, in my solution you have `el`, use that in your if condition.

```js
function check(box) {
  var el = box.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  var radioId = "";
  el.forEach(element => {
    radioId = element.id
  });

  //console.log(radioId);
  document.getElementById(radioId).click();
  document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("checked");
  });
  if ((el[0].checked = true)) {
    box.classList.add("checked");
  }
  return false;
}

function showhide(elem) {
event.stopPropagation();
  var cont = elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling;

  if (cont.style.display != "block") {
    cont.style.display = "block";
    elem.innerHTML = "hide";
  } else {
    cont.style.display = "none";
    elem.innerHTML = "show";
  }
  return false;
  
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.hiddenstuff {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 1</h3>
  <input id="radio1" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
    <div class="hiddenstuff">
      You see me now
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this)">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
<br />
<div class="box" onclick="check(this)">
  <h3>This is div 2</h3>
  <input id="radio2" name="field" type="radio" />
  <div>
    <div class="hiddenstuff">
      You see me now
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="link" onclick="showhide(this);">show</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: el.forEach(element => {
    radioId = element.id
  });

This part is throwing a syntax error in IE11.

Comment: @MiaSno I really don't see reason why it should. element.id is obliviously well supported, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id as well as Array.prototype.forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach as you can see in on links, they both have IE support. Please make sure you don't have illegal characters inside. Or ty to use some other looping technique from this well documented topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript . I am on Mac OS now, So i can not test it.

Comment: it's the arrow annotation that is not supported :)

Comment: I think I can use a polyfill for the forEach but for the arrow annotation I have to refactor that without arrow annotation. ugh nevermind forEach IE11 doesn't like either. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @MiaSno well I dont like old IE's ;) anyways if you really must support it you can allways use first option 1. Sequential for loop from link I provided.